# codeigniter file upload failure with no error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Following is the code to upload multiple files through codeigniter, but this does not work.  It always throws error "file not selected"

HTML

```
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/dashboard/upload">

<table class="custom">
    <tr> <th>Title</th> <th>Image</th> </tr>
    <tr><td><input  type="text" name="title[]" id="title1"/></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="userfile[1][]" multiple id="userfile1" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="addbutton" value="Add More"></td></tr>
</table>

<table class="custom1" id="repeat-div"></table>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var i = $('#repeat-div').size();
    var j = i+1;

  $('#addbutton').click(function(){

    $('<tr><td><input type="text" name="title[]" id="title'+j+'"/></td><td><input type="file" id="userfile'+j+'" name="userfile['+j+'][]" multiple /></td></td></tr>').appendTo($('#repeat-div'));
++i;
j++;

});
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
function upload(){
  print_r($_FILES);exit;
```

}

This gives the output like this.

```
Array
(
[userfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => file1.pdf
                        [1] => file2.pdf
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => file3.pdf
                        [1] => file4.pdf
                    )

            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => application/pdf
                        [1] => application/pdf
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => application/pdf
                        [1] => application/pdf
                    )

            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => D:\wamp\tmp\php436C.tmp
                        [1] => D:\wamp\tmp\php436D.tmp
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => D:\wamp\tmp\php436E.tmp
                        [1] => D:\wamp\tmp\php436F.tmp
                    )

            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                    )

            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 191
                        [1] => 1267
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 98591
                        [1] => 73302
                    )

            )

    )
```

)
Please suggest on how to upload these files.

Comment: try print_r($error) before exit

Comment: check folder permission where you are uploading files

Comment: print_r($error) says Array ( [error] =>

You did not select a file to upload.
)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first go to [File Uploading Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).Now about your question as i know you didn't pass name of the file field to the `do_upload()` method.So here is the modification in your code ,

```
foreach($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i+1] as $file){
        //your logic

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('images')){    
          $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        exit; }
        else
        redirect('dashboard/failure');
    }
```